# How do you rollback during Django shell session after causing DatabaseError?

Tags: django

I used to know how to do this, but I forgot.  Sometimes, while using the Django shell, you make a mistake and cause the transaction to become aborted.  After that, any further queries you do will result in DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block.  However, I think there is a way to rollback the transaction when this happens manually so you don't have to restart your session.  Can anyone tell me what it is?

This bug report (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10813) makes reference to the technique but doesn't explain it.  Running django.db.transaction.rollback results in "TransactionManagementError: This code isn't under transaction management".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This happens to me all the time when using Postgres, and it's really irritating.

You want:

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.rollback()
```

Most of the time this is fine (and in my experience, it's safe to ignore the `TransactionManagementError`).

Comment: Thanks.  I have also taken to just putting my session under transaction management from the get-go.  Makes things a little safer anyway.

Answer (score 7):

This is slightly better because you get no stack trace about `TransactionManagementError`:

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.rollback_unless_managed()
```

Comment: Thanks! I had some code loading in `signals.py` which referenced ORM `.get()` before syncdb could occur, and this was the band-aid I needed. (You know, instead of actually fixing my code to avoid the database query altogether!)